# Ubuntu 14.04 login crash/black screen after latest update

Tags: 14.04, boot, drivers, nvidia, login

my laptop crashes just before login, either with the ubuntu-sign or changing to black screen. Never had this issue before. Yesterday I added the new updates, had also all the time some reporting bugs due to my nvidia-card, but never actual probs

Laptop: Dell XPS 14 Z, OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Started by solving this prob by checking bios, and running a dell-integrated hardware check: nothing. Than passing the freeze by ctrl-alt-f1 and login and trying to start with "startx": changed again to black screen. tried to download: bios-repair: failed.

Iam not such a skilled linux-user, just able to solve simple-probs in a simple ubuntu-set-up, so after reading some similar prob-reports i don't now where to start by fixing or thats the prob really about? (i suggest something about the graphic-card)

Would be great if you could help me with some hints! thx

Comment: check this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: thx a lot, nvidia it was...

Answer (score 1):

1- First, you must uninstall `nvidia` packages. `apt-get purge nvidia-*`
2- Try re-install `ubuntu-desktop`.
3- Reconfigure `lightdm` package. (`dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`)
4- Reboot

It must work.